# Get P-VALUE from mean, sd, and n

Tags: r, dplyr, anova, p-value

I have this data including mean, sd, and count for each group (n=4). So I have for different groups and I need to get P-VALUE and Analysis of Variance (ANOVA) and the F-test for each row. I have tried some functions such as ind.oneway.second and  t.test.from.summary, but I get errors. Could you suggest me a method that I can get p-value and f-test for each row among for groups.

```
structure(list(VAR = c("AGEFY19", "Onset_age", "FEMALE"), mean_1 = c(41.947791, 
30.830435, 0.196787), count_1 = c(249, 249, 249), std_1 = c(10.167612, 
10.848377, 0.398371), conf_1 = c(1.262919, 1.402029, 0.049482
), conf_hi_1 = c(43.21071, 32.232464, 0.246269), conf_lo_1 = c(40.684873, 
29.428406, 0.147306), mean_2 = c(41.313953, 31.797468, 0.151163
), count_2 = c(86, 86, 86), std_2 = c(8.109924, 8.03738, 0.360308
), conf_2 = c(1.71405, 1.772381, 0.076152), conf_hi_2 = c(43.028004, 
33.569849, 0.227315), conf_lo_2 = c(39.599903, 30.025088, 0.075011
), mean_3 = c(39.379032, 28.577586, 0.25), count_3 = c(124, 124, 
124), std_3 = c(8.240878, 8.716951, 0.434769), conf_3 = c(1.450503, 
1.586323, 0.076525), conf_hi_3 = c(40.829536, 30.163909, 0.326525
), conf_lo_3 = c(37.928529, 26.991263, 0.173475), mean_4 = c(40.5, 
30.181818, 0.242857), count_4 = c(70, 70, 70), std_4 = c(8.07169, 
7.302074, 0.431906), conf_4 = c(1.890913, 1.761693, 0.10118), 
    conf_hi_4 = c(42.390913, 31.943512, 0.344037), conf_lo_4 = c(38.609087, 
    28.420125, 0.141677)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be using `rpsychi` package.
Here is the anova for row1. To get it for the other rows just adopt by `slice(2)` or `slice(3)`

```
library(dplyr)
library(rpsychi)

# get row 1 from your df
row1 <- df %>%  
  slice(1)

# select mean and return a vector
row1.mean <- row1 %>% 
  select(contains("mean")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE)

# select sd and return a vector
row1.sd <- row1 %>% 
  select(contains("std")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE)

# select count and return a vector
row1.n <- row1 %>% 
  select(contains("count")) %>% 
  slice(1) %>% unlist(use.names = FALSE)

# do the anov on row1
row1.anova <- ind.oneway.second(row1.mean, row1.sd, row1.n)

# show results
row1.anova
```

Output:

```
$anova.table
               SS  df      MS     F
Between (A)   574   3 191.364 2.279
Within      44078 525  83.957      
Total       44652 528              

$omnibus.es
      etasq etasq.lower etasq.upper 
      0.013       0.000       0.033 

$raw.contrasts
    mean.diff  lower upper   std
1-2     0.634 -1.618 2.885 1.146
1-3     2.569  0.590 4.547 1.007
1-4     1.448 -0.987 3.883 1.240
2-3     1.935 -0.591 4.461 1.286
2-4     0.814 -2.084 3.712 1.475
3-4    -1.121 -3.812 1.570 1.370

$standardized.contrasts
        es  lower upper   std
1-2  0.069 -0.177 0.315 0.125
1-3  0.280  0.064 0.496 0.110
1-4  0.158 -0.108 0.424 0.135
2-3  0.211 -0.065 0.487 0.140
2-4  0.089 -0.227 0.405 0.161
3-4 -0.122 -0.416 0.171 0.149

$power
 small medium  large 
 0.469  0.999  1.000
```